# Why context sensitive encoding to prevent XSS?

Tags: xss, encoding

OWASP [recommends](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) that context-sensitive encoding needs to be done. Please help me in getting a couple of strong "code examples" on why context sensitive based encoding needs to be done and why HTML encoding alone won't help in those cases?

I know that it can help for unquoted attributes (is also explained in [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728/will-html-encoding-prevent-all-kinds-of-xss-attacks)) but for now let us assume that entire world is using quoted attributes [I know its impossible but just let's assume :/], can you help me in providing two more examples where HTML encoding will not help and lead to XSS attacks which would be protected if we had used context-sensitive encoding functions provided by [3](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder) (this is the only context sensitive encoding library present in market that I know of)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to use a few examples where various forms of HTML encoding will not help.  All of these are cases I have actually seen in practice.  I will use `{{foo}}` for the variable to be substituted.  I assume HTML encoding involves replacing `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.  If you also escape both single and double quotes, some of them will no longer be exploitable, but some will be.

```
<script>var x = '{{foo}}';</script>
<a href="{{foo}}">Clicky</a>
<script>/** Comment {{foo}} */</script>
<html ng-app='myapp'>{{foo}}</html>
```

You might want to check out this [blog post for more details](https://security.googleblog.com/2009/03/reducing-xss-by-way-of-automatic.html).